# Can I use JDT to generate control flow graph?

Tags: code-analysis, eclipse-jdt, static-code-analysis, soot, control-flow-graph

Does JDT provide any APIs to generate control flow graph?
I used soot to generate control flow graph,but can I use JDT to generate control flow graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDT sure provides all necessary information, but you may have to invest some code of your own, to get *exactly* that data structure you are seeking.

Much depends on the level of detail you are interested in: A call graph between methods? Detailed flow of basic blocks within a method? A combination of both?

If your interest is related in spirit to refactoring, you may get some inspiration from the internal code in JDT/UI that is used for flow analysis on behalf of refactorings. Have a look at the following sections of source code:

- data structures below [org.eclipse.jdt.ui/core refactoring/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/code/flow](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/core%20refactoring/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/code/flow)
- usage of the above in classes like

  - [org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/code/CallInliner.java](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/core%20refactoring/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/code/CallInliner.java)
  - [org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/code/ExtractMethodAnalyzer.java](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/core%20refactoring/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/code/ExtractMethodAnalyzer.java)